# Logging the username of a user that modifies values in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a large shared (OneDrive) Excel file where multiple people are meant to update the inputs of a model. I would like to log on each row the username and date of the last user who modified that row. Ideally I would need this to be a value, not a formula, because otherwise when another user opens the file the formula will change all usernames in the file change to theirs.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: Get the user: `environ("Username")` - Get the date: `now`. Use the `Change`-Event of a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, excel.worksheet.change is what I was looking for thank you